# Changing order of expectation and integration

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-analysis

If I know that

$$E\biggl(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t}X^{2}_{t}dt\biggr)<\infty$$

Can I say

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}E (e^{-\lambda t}X^{2}_{t})dt<\infty$$

Or do I need that $E(X_{t}^{2})<\infty$

Comment: Yes. Fubini/Tonelli implies they're equal, regardless if they're infinite or not.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I though the were only equal if one of them is finite. Is this incorrect?

Comment: No, for nonnegative functions they're just equal full stop (although the answer that recently appeared below points out a technicality, that the integrand needs to be measurable on the product algebra, but often we assume stochastic processes have good joint measurability properties. )

Comment: (Didn’t quite read your comment right, so I’ll clarify. The assertion that they’re equal includes the possibility of both being infinite. If one is infinite, the other is infinite. If one is finite with some value, the other is finite with the same value.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ denote the probability space $X_t$ is defined.

You can do this without any additional assumptions on $X_t$ besides that the map $X_t : \Omega \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ defined by $(\omega, t) \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is measurable on the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal B([0,\infty))$, where $\mathcal B([0,\infty))$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,\infty)$ (which seems to be true in your case.)

This is because Fubini's theorem for positive functions (noting that $(\omega, t) \mapsto e^{-\lambda t}X_t(\omega)^2$ is a positive function):
$$\mathbb E\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}X_t^2\,dt\right] = \int_{\Omega}\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}X_t(\omega)^2\,dt\,dP(\omega) = \int_0^\infty \int_{\Omega}e^{-\lambda t}X_t(\omega)^2\,dP(\omega)\,dt = \int_0^\infty \mathbb E[e^{-\lambda t}X_t^2]\,dt.$$